# android bundle won't load but apk will

Tags: android, react-native, google-play-console

I'm in the process of working on a React Native app that I took over the code base for. For some reason the build I pushed to the play store beta hangs at the splash screen, but the same apk works fine when installed (instead of the aab). I don't see anything in the android studio logcat that would indicate the source of the issue.

Comment: Sounds like a signing key issue. Make sure you have whitelisted the app signing key (SHA1 certificate is available in the App Signing page of the Play Console) in all the APIs you are using, e.g. in the Google Cloud Console if you're using Google APIs.