# Firebase Authentication fails in aab, but not in APK (React-Native)

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

I'm having issues with signing into my app whenever I test it in Closed Testing.

My app uses Firebase for authentication, I have three variants set up for my React Native project (development, demo, production) and can confirm that my scripts, I run to build the app, point to the correct environment variables and app points to the correctly database and api when built in debug mode. When I generated a release APK and send the files to the testers, they usually don't have issues with logging in. (This was before I opened a google play account) However, whenever I uploaded the aab (using `./gradlew bundleRelease`) for closed testing, sometimes users could pass the login screen, sometimes they couldn't.

I can confirm the release is being signed correctly. I was able to debug the app locally, and generate a release successfully. Locally, in both release and debug mode, Authentication, API calls were correctly. Just fails whenever I generate and upload the app bundle to google play console. I tried the google's help desk, they recommended me to use only one track per app in closed testing. Therefore, I closed all but one (alpha), still having this issue.

These are the questions I searched  [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61464119/android-bundle-wont-load-but-apk-will) [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61464119/android-bundle-wont-load-but-apk-will) [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36999751/google-signin-not-working-in-release-mode-apk-android)

I was thinking of adding the SHA-1 certificate fingerprint to each of the firebase project, but I don't know if that's the most accurate approach to fixing this issue.

React Native  0.67.3
Node 16.13.1
NPM 8.1.4

Here is my bundle.gradle

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"
apply plugin: "com.apollographql.apollo"
import com.android.build.OutputFile
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
/**
 * The react.gradle file registers a task for each build variant (e.g. bundleDebugJsAndAssets
 * and bundleReleaseJsAndAssets).
 * These basically call `react-native bundle` with the correct arguments during the Android build
 * cycle. By default, bundleDebugJsAndAssets is skipped, as in debug/dev mode we prefer to load the
 * bundle directly from the development server. Below you can see all the possible configurations
 * and their defaults. If you decide to add a configuration block, make sure to add it before the
 * `apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"` line.
 *
 * project.ext.react = [
 *   // the name of the generated asset file containing your JS bundle
 *   bundleAssetName: "index.android.bundle",
 *
 *   // the entry file for bundle generation. If none specified and
 *   // "index.android.js" exists, it will be used. Otherwise "index.js" is
 *   // default. Can be overridden with ENTRY_FILE environment variable.
 *   entryFile: "index.android.js",
 *
 *   // https://reactnative.dev/docs/performance#enable-the-ram-format
 *   bundleCommand: "ram-bundle",
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in debug mode
 *   bundleInDebug: false,
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in release mode
 *   bundleInRelease: true,
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in another build variant (if configured).
 *   // See http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Build-Variants
 *   // The configuration property can be in the following formats
 *   //         'bundleIn${productFlavor}${buildType}'
 *   //         'bundleIn${buildType}'
 *   // bundleInFreeDebug: true,
 *   // bundleInPaidRelease: true,
 *   // bundleInBeta: true,
 *
 *   // whether to disable dev mode in custom build variants (by default only disabled in release)
 *   // for example: to disable dev mode in the staging build type (if configured)
 *   devDisabledInStaging: true,
 *   // The configuration property can be in the following formats
 *   //         'devDisabledIn${productFlavor}${buildType}'
 *   //         'devDisabledIn${buildType}'
 *
 *   // the root of your project, i.e. where "package.json" lives
 *   root: "../../",
 *
 *   // where to put the JS bundle asset in debug mode
 *   jsBundleDirDebug: "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/debug",
 *
 *   // where to put the JS bundle asset in release mode
 *   jsBundleDirRelease: "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/release",
 *
 *   // where to put drawable resources / React Native assets, e.g. the ones you use via
 *   // require('./image.png')), in debug mode
 *   resourcesDirDebug: "$buildDir/intermediates/res/merged/debug",
 *
 *   // where to put drawable resources / React Native assets, e.g. the ones you use via
 *   // require('./image.png')), in release mode
 *   resourcesDirRelease: "$buildDir/intermediates/res/merged/release",
 *
 *   // by default the gradle tasks are skipped if none of the JS files or assets change; this means
 *   // that we don't look at files in android/ or ios/ to determine whether the tasks are up to
 *   // date; if you have any other folders that you want to ignore for performance reasons (gradle
 *   // indexes the entire tree), add them here. Alternatively, if you have JS files in android/
 *   // for example, you might want to remove it from here.
 *   inputExcludes: ["android/**", "ios/**"],
 *
 *   // override which node gets called and with what additional arguments
 *   nodeExecutableAndArgs: ["node"],
 *
 *   // supply additional arguments to the packager
 *   extraPackagerArgs: []
 * ]
 */

project.ext.react = [
    enableHermes: false,  // clean and rebuild if changing
]

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"


project.ext.envConfigFiles = [
   productionrelease: ".env.production",
   productiondebug: ".env.production",
   developmentrelease: ".env",
   developmentdebug: ".env",
   demorelease: ".env.demo",
   demodebug: ".env.demo",
]
apply from: project(':react-native-config').projectDir.getPath() + "/dotenv.gradle"
/**
 * Set this to true to create two separate APKs instead of one:
 *   - An APK that only works on ARM devices
 *   - An APK that only works on x86 devices
 * The advantage is the size of the APK is reduced by about 4MB.
 * Upload all the APKs to the Play Store and people will download
 * the correct one based on the CPU architecture of their device.
 */
def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false

/**
 * Run Proguard to shrink the Java bytecode in release builds.
 */
def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

/**
 * The preferred build flavor of JavaScriptCore.
 *
 * For example, to use the international variant, you can use:
 * `def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc-intl:+'`
 *
 * The international variant includes ICU i18n library and necessary data
 * allowing to use e.g. `Date.toLocaleString` and `String.localeCompare` that
 * give correct results when using with locales other than en-US.  Note that
 * this variant is about 6MiB larger per architecture than default.
 */
def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc:+'

/**
 * Whether to enable the Hermes VM.
 *
 * This should be set on project.ext.react and that value will be read here. If it is not set
 * on project.ext.react, JavaScript will not be compiled to Hermes Bytecode
 * and the benefits of using Hermes will therefore be sharply reduced.
 */
def enableHermes = project.ext.react.get("enableHermes", false);

/**
 * Architectures to build native code for in debug.
 */
def nativeArchitectures = project.getProperties().get("reactNativeDebugArchitectures")

android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.work"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 15
        versionName "2.6"
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "arm64-v8a", "x86_64"
        }
    }
    signingConfigs {
        debug {
            storeFile file('debug.keystore')
            storePassword 'android'
            keyAlias 'androiddebugkey'
            keyPassword 'android'
        }
         release {
            if (project.hasProperty('MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_FILE')) {
                storeFile file(MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_FILE)
                storePassword MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_PASSWORD
                keyAlias MYAPP_UPLOAD_KEY_ALIAS
                keyPassword MYAPP_UPLOAD_KEY_PASSWORD
            }
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            // Specifies a sorted list of build types that the plugin should try to use when a direct variant match with a local module dependency is not possible.
            matchingFallbacks = ['debug', 'release']
            if (nativeArchitectures) {
                ndk {
                    abiFilters nativeArchitectures.split(',')
                }
            }
        }
        release {
            // Caution! In production, you need to generate your own keystore file.
            // see https://reactnative.dev/docs/signed-apk-android.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        }
    }
flavorDimensions "default"
  productFlavors {
    production {
        resValue "string",  "app_name", "work"
    }
    demo {
        resValue "string",  "app_name", "work_demo"
    }
    development {
        resValue "string",  "app_name", "work_dev"
    }
  }
    // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits.html
            // Example: versionCode 1 will generate 1001 for armeabi-v7a, 1002 for x86, etc.
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a": 1, "x86": 2, "arm64-v8a": 3, "x86_64": 4]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        defaultConfig.versionCode * 1000 + versionCodes.get(abi)
            }

        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    //noinspection GradleDynamicVersion
    implementation project(":react-native-webview")
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1"
    implementation "androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.0.0"
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
  // Apollo core
    implementation "com.apollographql.apollo:apollo-runtime:2.4.6"
  // firebase
  implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:29.0.4')
  //analytics
  implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics"
  //auth
  implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth"
    //analytics
  implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics"
    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
        exclude group:'com.facebook.fbjni'
    }

    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-network-plugin:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
        exclude group:'com.facebook.flipper'
        exclude group:'com.squareup.okhttp3', module:'okhttp'
    }

    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-fresco-plugin:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
        exclude group:'com.facebook.flipper'
    }

    if (enableHermes) {
        def hermesPath = "../../node_modules/hermes-engine/android/";
        debugImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-debug.aar")
        releaseImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-release.aar")
    } else {
        implementation jscFlavor
    }
}

// Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
// puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.implementation
    into 'libs'
}

apply from: file("../../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle"); applyNativeModulesAppBuildGradle(project)
```

Tried to be as thorough as possible. Thank you for your time and please let me know if there's anything I can provide to make this easier on your end.

Answer (score 1):

Just as a guess, when you send an AAB to google, it repackages it for you into per-device-profile APKs and *signs those with a different key*, which you need to download and configure as a valid key for Firebase - something many people forget to do. Could that be your problem?

Discussion of how it works:
https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/faq#app-signing

Pointer to where to get the SHA of your Play App Signing key:
https://developers.google.com/android/guides/client-auth#using_play_app_signing

Comment: Thank you so much Mike for answering. After reading your comment this is what I have tried - Went to Settings - App Integrity to view the Signings Keys - followed the commands on developers.google.com/android/guides/… to make ensure the correct signing key is being used (it is) - added the upload signing key to firebase project, redownloaded the google-service json and replaced old json file in the project. - create a new track in closed testing. - following morning I tried installing, the same issue occurs. Am I missing something here?

Comment: What is missing perhaps is the output from `adb logcat` on the device when expected API calls fail. They should contain information required for further diagnosis I hope

Comment: Hi Mike, have you found any solution? i have the same issue and didn't know what to do.

Comment: @QadirAli I literally posted a solution as the answer here that you are commenting on. I'm confused?

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps

1. Go to Google Play Console
2. Select your app from dashboard, then go to 'Setup'. Under 'Setup', click on 'App signing'. Scroll down and copy the sha256_cert fingerprint under 'Digital Asset Links JSON'.
3. Copy this sha256 cert fingerprint in your Firebase project settings.
   That's all.